# EaselJS (0.8.2.min and up)- Moving JSON generated Sprite map XY when character moves

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, easeljs, sprite-sheet

easeljs-0.8.2.min
Tiled JSON exported Tile-map was used.

I have the tile-map already generated using Sprite Class (Bitmap Class is deprecated now Ya that took a while to figure out). So it is standard 32x32 square generated orthogonal.

I have a character SpriteSheet that moves by keyboard listening events. When I move the character Right I want the map that was generated to pan and move when the character does, so it looks like the character is traveling and you can see the rest of the map that is off canvas.

```
  spriteContainer = new createjs.Container();

  for ( var y = 0; y < layerData.height; y++) {
    for ( var x = 0; x < layerData.width; x++) {
      // create a new Bitmap for each cell
      currentMap = new createjs.Sprite(tilesetSheet);

      // layer data has single dimension array
      var idx = x + y * layerData.width;
      // tilemap data uses 1 as first value, EaselJS uses 0 (sub 1 to load correct tile)
      tileLoad = layerData.data[idx] - 1;
      currentMap.gotoAndStop(tileLoad);

    // orthogonal tile positioning based on X Y order from Tiled
      if(moveX == undefined || moveX == 0){
        moveX= 0;
      } else {}
      if(moveY == undefined || moveY == 0){
        moveY= 0;
      } else {}

      currentMap.x = (x * tilewidth - x) + moveX;
      currentMap.y = (y * tileheight) + moveY;

      // Pan X & Y
      // X Minus Pans Right
      // Y Minus Pans Down
      // currentMap.x = currentMap.x + 1;
      // currentMap.y = currentMap.y - 2;

      mapX = currentMap.x;
      mapY = currentMap.y;

      currentMap.setBounds(mapX, mapY, tilewidth, tileheight);

      spriteContainer.addChild(currentMap);

      // Add bitmap to stage
      stage.addChild(currentMap);

    }
  }
```

So I found in EaselJS has a class called, SpriteContainer, I am thinking this is the solution I may need to get this to work. So Map gets generated and on the right arrow key listener for pressing now I tried:

// Set Map
spriteContainer.x = spriteContainer.x += charWalkSpeed;

My Debugger is showing that the X coordinates does go up as I press the right arrow key, however, the map does not move and it stays stationary. Been stuck on this for a Month now and am absolutely stuck. I have a working example of what I have so far, but I think the source code supplied might be sufficient enough

Comment: SpriteContainer is a replacement Container that uses a WebGL approach to render faster. I would stick with Sprite.

Comment: How are you moving the sprite? Are you incrementing the x position on keypress? Are you updating the stage after changing it? Can you post that code?

Comment: Well Yes the Sprite class gets iterated over and over per square.

The Character gets added like:
`code`
 HeroXCoordinates = HeroPlay0.x += charWalkSpeed;
`/code`
Yes on key press which does the gotoAndPlay on press release, the character uses the SpriteSheet class because it has animations specific to what it does.<br>
My idea with the container is to hold all those squares and move then x or y. In the code posted previously, the position is oved by:    
`code`
currentMap.x = currentMap.x + 1;
//                currentMap.y = currentMap.y - 2;
`/code`

Comment: So in theory, on the keypress, if I did :
currentMap.x = currentMap.x += charWalkSpeed;
The map should move, yet only one square will move

Answer (score 0):

Heh, figured it out. Two Damn months and finally!

**currentMap.parent.x** ! So things are panning as they should, I even like the fact that it moves Collision objects too! Sadly it moves the header bar, so making a new function that tells the header bar it needs to stay static. Not too bad.

My next task is getting the tilemap to not pan if it reaches the end of the tilemap. So you do not see the canvas background. I have the header static, so how I got the panning to happen might clue me in on how to prevent pan bleeding.